# Angular scope doesn't update even with apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with Angular's scope:

Init Angular:

```
<html lang="en"  ng-app="ant101App" ng-controller="regFormController as reg">
```

Script:

```
script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('ant101App',[]);
    app.controller('regFormController', function() {
        this.message = null;
        if ((''+this.fname).length > 15) {
                this.message = 'First name should be less than 16 characters!';
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{reg.message}}</p>

 <input ng-model="reg.fname" type="text" name="firstname" class="afirst-name-box" placeholder="First name" required>
```

When I enter first name, reg.message doesnt update.
When I use aplly(), it even caused error, and just displayed {{reg.message}} in html page

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('ant101App',[]);
    app.controller('regFormController', function() {
        this.message = null;
        this.$apply(function(){
            if ((''+this.fname).length > 15) {
                    this.message = 'First name should be less than 16 characters!';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So how can I update reg.message when reg.fname changed?

Comment: you should inject $scope in order to use angularjs bindings and $apply

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp help for $scope

Comment: @MohammadMc No, OP doesn't need $scope. And $apply too.

Comment: Also, your controller code doesn't automatically run when a value is changed.

Comment: $apply is for using outside of angular thread like timeout , for keep tracking of your values use $watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to validate the input on keyPress.

You should be doing this.

```
<input ng-model="reg.fname" type="text" name="firstname" class="afirst-name-box" placeholder="First name" required ng-keypress="reg.validateName()">
```

and in controller

```
app.controller('regFormController', function() {
        this.message = null;
        this.validateName = function() {
           if ((''+this.fname).length > 15) {
                this.message = 'First name should be less than 16 characters!';
           }
        };       
    });
```

Comment: @T J, see his html code for controllerAs

Comment: Ah... that's not present in your answer... nvm.

Answer (score 0):

You can run update function with *ng-change* directive. Working example in Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/KH6bhumLjz7VR1dmE16r?p=preview

In controller:

```
this.updateName = function() {
      if ((''+this.fname).length > 15) {
            this.message = 'First name should be less than 16 characters!';
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <input ng-change="reg.updateName()" type="text" required="" placeholder="First name" class="afirst-name-box" name="firstname" ng-model="reg.fname" />
```